# Abrir Página com uma Tecla

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Na página, quem apertar tecla <kbd>z</kbd> abre meu URL.

Não sei se é possivel, mas queria sem ter que usar <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> e/ou <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

```css
#teclas {display:none;}
```

```html
<div id='teclas'>
<a accesskey='z' href='#zenphone'></a>
</div>
```

O código que estou usando acima tem que pressionar <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> ou outra coisa em outro navegador ou sistema operacional, queria que abrisse esse link com apenas pressionando uma letra ou número do teclado.

Answer (score 1):

Sim! É possivél ouvir o click da tecla <kbd>z</kbd> e abrir um URL especifico. Mas, para o tal deve usar o JavaScript. E nesse casso ficaria assim:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {

    // Pode ver a lista dos códigos  [aqui][1]
    if (event.key === 'z' || event.keyCode === 122) {

      let href = document.getElementById("teclas-z").getAttribute("href"); // Busca o URL

      window.open(href, '_blank'); // Abre a URL numa nova aba

    }
  })
};
```

```css
#teclas {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="teclas">
  <a accesskey="z" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" id="teclas-z"></a>
</div>
```

*Pode ver a lista dos códigos  [aqui](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)*

Comment: Não funcionou aqui não, testei em mais de um navegador, coloquei o numero do key codes e nada

Comment: @YasminGulosa troque `document.getElementById("teclas-z")[0]` por `document.getElementById("teclas-z")`, pois `document.getElementById` retorna apenas um elemento, sem array, logo `[0]` é desnecessário.

Comment: agora funcionou sem o [0] valeu

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Obrigado.

Comment: só faltou marcar como certo @YasminGulosa